# Trying to make a donut from blenderguru's tutorial

Tags: modeling

[image]
Im trying to bring down the frosting but for some reason it keeps cutting into the donut itself, im still new so i dont really know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,

Go to the little dropdown arrow next to the snap tool(The magnet icon) and make sure you have these exact settings:

[image]

These settings worked fine for me.

Some more things you should keep in mind:

1. The offset of your solidify modifier should  be +1 i.e. the thickness should come towards the outside

[image]

2. The icing and the donut should have uniform scale i.e it should have scale of 1 on X, Y and Z axis. If they don't have a uniform scale then you can make it uniform by going to object mode - > Press Ctrl + A and applying the scale.
   [image]
3. You have to be in edit mode to move the vertices and change the shape of icing.
4. Snapping has a limit, you can't drag the icing too far and expect to have no intersections between the donut and icing(In ur case it should work fine)

Comment: i have the exact settings and the "project individual elements" could it be the angle i was doing it at? i was looing straight at it a little

Comment: @Solfaris Did you move the frosting in edit mode from top view?

Comment: @HISEROD i dont think so, would that be the problem or the fix?

Comment: If you do it in object mode, the entire icing object will snap to the surface based on its origin; if you do it in edit mode, the individual vertices will be snapped to the surface.

Comment: well i used edit mode, so yea, but should i have done it at an angle or what bc im confused, i hardly know what im doing

Comment: @Solfaris I edited my answer Please read it....Hope it helps

Comment: well i was somehow able to fix it, but if i encounter the same problem ill be sure to check it out, thx a lot @MaulikSharma !